# How to unite two marshmellow schemes in one

Tags: python, marshmallow

I use marshmallow to validate my output. I have two marshmallow schemes

```
class IdentitiesList(Schema):
    items = fields.List(fields.String, required=True)

class UsersListSchema(Schema):
    items = fields.Nested(UserDescriptionSchema, many=True)
```

For several reasons I should unite this schemes in one, in several cases my service should return array of strings and use first scheme, in other case it should use second scheme.

It's possible? Or I should change my service behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by unite? Looks like you're looking for polymorphims. This is achieavable but it not easy to achieve (and to consume by the client). If I were you, I'd use two different resources and schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be my question was unclear, but I found solution. I created new Schema class where reloaded method `dump`:

```
class DetailedListSchema(Schema):
    """This schema serialize objects according input data"""
    def dump(self, obj, many=None, update_fields=True, **kwargs):
        if obj.get('items') == [] or (obj.get('items') and isinstance(obj['items'][0], UUID)):
            return IdentitiesList().dump(obj, many, update_fields, **kwargs)
        elif obj.get('items') and isinstance(obj['items'][0], User):
            return UsersListSchema().dump(obj, many, update_fields, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValueError
```